# Java 16 unbound on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, installation

I have Java JDK 16 installed on my computer and I've changed the JRE system library to JavaSE-16 in build paths of all of my Eclipse projects.

Here's the problem. I get errors saying that there are no compatible JREs installed in the workplace and some errors say that JavaSE-16 library is unbound. This happens despite installing Java 16 support from Eclipse Marketplace. Does anyone know a solution?

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers 2021-03 (4.19.0).
Java JDK 16.01.
Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

Comment: Have you told Eclipse about the Java 16 install in the 'Java > Installed JREs' page of the Preferences?

Comment: @greg-449 I have Eclipse's JRE in C:\Users\igora\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955\jre.

Comment: That is the Java 15 that comes with Eclipse. You must add the Java 16 install to that list. Eclipse only considers the Java installs you tell it about.